# Contact cards in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have long back deleted a number from my contacts list. Today I received a message from that number. On checking, WhatsApp shows this message `Found one contact card for this number` .

Can someone please tell me where does it find this contact? It's not yet saved in my contact list.

Comment: Sounds like WhatsApp is maintaining an internal list of contacts separate from your device contact list.

Comment: Where could such a list be stored?

Comment: That depends on WhatsApp - it will either be saved to external or internal app storage on your device, and perhaps even your account is synced with WhatsApp servers over the network.  The point is, WhatsApp is maintaining data.  I recommend investigating WhatsApp's settings and/or reaching out to them for support.

Comment: WhatsApp can collect contact information if it is shared in chats (or groups). I solved my problem by deleting all the contacts cards sent to various people/groups via WhatsApp.